# Spring Data "TimeoutException" when trying to "find" documents in Couchbase, even when using pageable

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase

Using `Spring-Data` we are trying to get slices of `Cat` from our `Couchbase` 's Pets bucket.

We have special index for such queries:

```
CREATE INDEX cats_by_ownerId_and_name_idx ON `pets`(ownerId ASC, name) WHERE _class = 'com.example.Cat'
```

The code looks like that:

```
Slice<Cat> slice;
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1000, Sort.by("id").ascending());
do {
   log.debug("Getting slice No. {} of cats from DB", sliceCounter++);
   slice = catsRepository.findAllByOwnerIdAndName("123", "Oscar", pageable);       
   ...
} while (slice.hasNext());
```

The code above works ok when the total number of `Cat`s is few dozens of thousands. (e.g. works OK for 50K Cats).

But if we have 100K Cats, we get the TimeoutException right in the first iteration of the loop:

```
Getting slice No. 0 of cats from DB
c.l.i.s.c.AsyncConfiguration   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","r":"127.0.0.1:8093","s":"n1ql","c":"1E8CB73B19B0255D/FFFFFFFFF24214C9","t":7500000,"i":"55f1afdb-5757-4b4b-8321-fc9a7003e3a8","l":"127.0.0.1:56365"}; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","r":"127.0.0.1:8093","s":"n1ql","c":"1E8CB73B19B0255D/FFFFFFFFF24214C9","t":7500000,"i":"55f1afdb-5757-4b4b-8321-fc9a7003e3a8","l":"127.0.0.1:56365"}

org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","r":"127.0.0.1:8093","s":"n1ql","c":"1E8CB73B19B0255D/FFFFFFFFF24214C9","t":7500000,"i":"55f1afdb-5757-4b4b-8321-fc9a7003e3a8","l":"127.0.0.1:56365"}; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","r":"127.0.0.1:8093","s":"n1ql","c":"1E8CB73B19B0255D/FFFFFFFFF24214C9","t":7500000,"i":"55f1afdb-5757-4b4b-8321-fc9a7003e3a8","l":"127.0.0.1:56365"}
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CouchbaseExceptionTranslator.java:122) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.execute(CouchbaseTemplate.java:544) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.queryN1QL(CouchbaseTemplate.java:498) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findByN1QL(CouchbaseTemplate.java:433) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeSliced(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:189) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeDependingOnType(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:129) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.findAllByProjectIdAndBuiltWithIndex(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:206) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.findAllByOwnerIdAndName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","r":"127.0.0.1:8093","s":"n1ql","c":"1E8CB73B19B0255D/FFFFFFFFF24214C9","t":7500000,"i":"55f1afdb-5757-4b4b-8321-fc9a7003e3a8","l":"127.0.0.1:56365"}
at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.query(CouchbaseBucket.java:634) ~[java-client-2.7.1.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.query(CouchbaseBucket.java:556) ~[java-client-2.7.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate$8.doInBucket(CouchbaseTemplate.java:501) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate$8.doInBucket(CouchbaseTemplate.java:498) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.execute(CouchbaseTemplate.java:541) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: {"b":"pets","r":"127.0.0.1:8093","s":"n1ql","c":"1E8CB73B19B0255D/FFFFFFFFF24214C9","t":7500000,"i":"55f1afdb-5757-4b4b-8321-fc9a7003e3a8","l":"127.0.0.1:56365"}
at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:131) ~[java-client-2.7.1.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:127) ~[java-client-2.7.1.jar:na]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onTimeout(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:166) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber$TimeoutTask.call(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:191) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
... 3 common frames omitted
```

We tried to implement the a change in the way the index is built ([as was mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362185/spring-data-timeoutexception-when-calling-delete-documents-with-pagination-i) but it had no effect.

**Edit**

Changing the Spring-Data method to one of these also didn't help:

```
findByOwnerIdAndName
findTop1000ByOwnerIdAndName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when we removed the `Sort.by("id")` from the creation of the `Pageable` object.

From that:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1000, Sort.by("id"));
```

To That:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1000);
```